# for cycle in copulapdf

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have to perform a copulapdf analysis and i need to create 8 different figures starting from varying nu (in this code called nuvar) from 1 to 8. I'm new in Matlab. I tried to write this for cycle but it doesn't works. Can someone help me please?

```
for nuvar= 1:1:8
    for numvar1= 1:1:8
    r=0.5;
    nu=1;
    u = linspace(0,1,20);
    [u1,u2] = meshgrid(u,u);
    rho1 = copulaparam('t',r,nu);
    H(nuvar, numvar1) = copulapdf('t',[u1(:),u2(:)],rho1,nuvar);
    surf(u1,u2,reshape(y,20,20))
    end 
end
```

I also tried to correct the script in this way:

```
r=0.5;
nu=1;
u = linspace(0,1,20);
rho1 = copulaparam('t',r,nu);
[u1,u2] = meshgrid(u,u);
    for numvar1= 1:1:8  
    H(nuvar, numvar1) = copulapdf('t',[u1(:),u2(:)],rho1,nuvar);
    surf(u1,u2,reshape(y,20,20))
    end 

 I have the same error "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch".
```

Comment: Please explain "doesn't work?" . Please see [mcve] and then [edit] your question accordingly

Comment: You're performing each of the 8 `nuvar` calculations 8 times, since you only use `numvar1` to index, not to set parameters. Also, the declarations for `r,nu,u,u1,u2,rho1` can be set outside the loop, as they do not depend on the loop indices (`nuvar` and `numvar1`), thus setting them `8*8=64` times to the same value is a bit pointless. Otherwise, what @SardarUsama said, please explain what didn't work. Do you get the same images? Incorrect images? Errors? An exploding computer?

Comment: @sardar Usama thank you for your suggestion. I receive an error " Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.". I don't know what it wrong.

Comment: I would drop the FOR loop right now, and try to have a first figure. Then you can program a FOR loop on success.

Comment: @Adriaan i've tried to write the script again with your suggestions but it gives me the same error. Can you write here the code corrected please? Really thanks :D

Comment: @ElisaMammoliti No, since this is not a code-writing service. Instead, [edit] the question, like Sardar asked you to in the first comment.

Comment: @Adriaan, done. What do you mean with "since you only use numvar1 to index, not to set parameters? how can i use numvar1 like a parameter in the for cycle to have 8 figures?

Comment: What is the purpose of `surf` in the loop when `u1`, `u2` and `y` are same for each iteration of your loops.  `u1`, `u2`, `rho1`, and `nuvar` are same  for each iteration of `numvar`, so what is the purpose of having them recalculated multiple times in the loop. Your question is not an MCVE and is very unclear. Please see [MCVE]  and [edit] your question accordingly